# Directory Override with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I need a special directory override of NGINX rules on my web server so that the rules that apply to /var/www/acme regarding CSS, JS, etc. do not apply to /var/www/acme/special. I have a /var/www containing my website under me.com (127.0.0.1 localhost setup). Inside there, I have an acme folder that uses a special framework for my PHP. However, I have a folder /var/www/acme/special that needs to not apply those same rules and just run like a regular PHP website. I'm stuck because when I apply the logic with a special location and try_files routine, along with a break, for /var/www/acme/special, then I get an HTTP 500 error that says "rewrite or internal redirection cycle when internally redirecting to '/acme/special////////////".

Here's my /etc/nginx/sites-available/me.com file for NGINX on Ubuntu 16.04. What am I doing wrong?

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www;

    index index.php index.html;

    server_name me.com www.me.com;


    location /acme/special {
        try_files $uri $uri/;
        break;
    }

    location ~ ^/acme/(.*(?<!boot))/css/(.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/acme/$1/views/assets/css/$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/acme/(.*(?<!boot))/js/(.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/acme/$1/views/assets/js/$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/acme/(.*(?<!boot))/img/(.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/acme/$1/views/assets/img/$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/acme/(.*)/fonts/(.*(?<!boot))$ {
        alias /var/www/acme/$1/views/assets/fonts/$2;
    }

    location ~ ^/acme/(.*)/boot/(.*)$ {
        alias /var/www/acme/$1/views/assets/boot/$2;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location @php {
        rewrite ^/acme/([^\/]+)/.*((?!index\.php).)*$ /acme/$1/index.php?query_string last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
location /acme/special {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

The last parameter of the `try_files` statement is the default action, so the `$uri/` term is not being treated as one of the *file* terms. Use `=404` or something like `/index.php` depending on your desired file-not-found response. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

The `break` is part of the rewrite module and has no purpose here.